# Insert multiple child records using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm creating a flick web application.

I have a flickrUser table and a flickrPhoto table

I've already inserted the flickrUser record and now i want to insert some flickrPhoto records;

```
FlickrPhoto:
 -photoid
 -flickruserid
 -id (PK)
```

here's how i'm trying to insert the flickrphoto records (flickrphoto is stored in MyPhoto table)

```
public void insertList(List<string> photoids, string flickruserid)
    {
        PicsPreciousLinqDataContext db = new PicsPreciousLinqDataContext();
        for (int i = 0; i < photoids.Count; i++)
        {              
                MyPhoto mf = new MyPhoto();
                mf.photoId = photoids[i];
                mf.source = "flickr";

                var query = from b in db.FlickrUsers
                            where b.nsid == flickruserid
                            select b;

                FlickrUser fUser = query.FirstOrDefault();
                mf.FlickrUserId = fUser.nsid;
                db.MyPhotos.InsertOnSubmit(mf);                
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();  <= Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.
    }
```

I've tried a few variations on this but also without success. What is the correct way to insert multiple child records?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What column is the primary key for MyPhoto? The error is simply telling you that there is already a row in the database with the key you're trying to add.

Comment: i have another column in MyPhoto called id that is PK and of type uniqueidentifier

Comment: As an aside, you are looking up the FlickrUser in each iteration of the loop, when nothing about that data changes.  You should do that only *once* before the loop.

Comment: Yes you're right :) I had moved it outside the loop but then used ctrl-z a few times until i had the code again i wanted to post here on stackoverflow that looked the best to me. I forgot to move it back out the loop but as you mention it now, i'll do this right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of id set by the database (i.e. NEWID() as default value, or auto-increment), then in your dbml designer, click on the column that's the primary key and ensure that the following properties have these values:

```
Auto Generated Value: True
Auto-Sync: OnInsert
Primary Key: True
```

If it is not set by the database, then instead of setting the first two properties above, you must create unique values for the Id column in your C# code for each row you insert.

This can be done with:

```
 Guid.NewGuid();
```

So in your code:

```
PicsPreciousLinqDataContext db = new PicsPreciousLinqDataContext();
...
MyPhoto mf = new MyPhoto();
            mf.photoId = photoids[i];
            mf.source = "flickr";
            mf.id = Guid.newGuid();
...
db.MyPhotos.InsertOnSubmit(mf);
```

for columns that are uniqueIdentifier type columns in the database.

Comment: Ok, using Guid.NewGuid() for the id attribute of the newly created MyPhoto works. How can is set this in the database? I don't want to call guid.newGuid everytime i need to insert a record... I've created my tables using visual studio and only set the type of the field to uniqueidentifier. Should i do something more?

Comment: I only know how to set it using the SQL Server management tool. But there is nothing wrong with setting it in code.

Comment: I'll look for some more information about uniqueidentifier in visual studio but your answer will do for now :) thx!

Comment: Please make it identity field and increment into 1, so you need not to give it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your **MyPhotos** Table, i suspect that it has the **userId** column as primary key .  It should be foreign key/reference key column.

add the following instead your code,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < photoids.Count; i++)
    {              
            MyPhoto mf = new MyPhoto();
            mf.photoId = photoids[i];
            mf.source = "flickr";

            var query = from b in db.FlickrUsers
                        where b.nsid == flickruserid
                        select b;

            FlickrUser fUser = query.FirstOrDefault();
            mf.FlickrUserId = fUser.nsid;
            db.MyPhotos.Add(mf);               
    }
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: i've updated my question, showing also the PK field 'id' in MyPhoto table. userid is foreign key. Can you help me out?